# is there a way to make awk keep track of changes that it makes

Tags: bash, csv, awk

I was wondering if there was a way to make awk output the number of changes that it has made, or somehow keep track of what it changes. For instance if there was a .csv file, in which I used awk to replace the word "the" with "it", would there be a way to make awk output how many times it had found and replaced "the" inside of the .csv file? I've been searching around on google + the rest of this site but have not been able to find anything, not sure if I am just working it the wrong way or something of the sort though, if someone could help me out with this though I would really appreciate it, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as far as I know, awk cannot give that substitution counts automatically. We have to sum the number manually somehow. for example, with your "the"->"it":

```
gawk '{x+=gsub("the","it");print} END{print "total changes:"x}' file.csv
```

Comment: +1 this is THE correct answer to the posted question so if it's not what the OP wants then (s)he needs to reword the question and give some sample input and expected output.

Comment: worked perfectly, thanks! like how it uses gsub as well, was planning on using that but was not sure how to implement the counting part

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you replace "the" with "it" in your awk script, increment a counter. Then print the counter at end of you awk script by putting it in the END block.

A simple example, you are only replacing "`the`"'s within in column 1:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}
     {if ($1 == "the") {$1 = "it"; counter++; print}}
     END{print counter}' input.csv
```

But what you are looking to do is simply count how many times the word / pattern "the" occurred inside the original .cvs file, you can simply do:

```
grep -c "the" input.csv
```

or depending on the format of your .csv:

```
grep -c " the," input.csv
```